# How can I have separate for loops (in separate columns) in a flask template?

Tags: html, css, for-loop, flask

The last link in my first `for` loop in my first column is also the link to the `header` in my second column where I have a second `for` loop. In this example the link for `Broccoli` is also creating a hyperlink in the text `Previous Ads` and I can't understand why.

[image]

There should not be any link in the `header` `Previous Ads`. I believe this is an HTML issue in a Flask  template so here is my code.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
<form action="{{ url_for('searched') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Search food" type ="search" name="search"/>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <h2>Live Ads</h2>
        <dl class="desc-info" style ="text-indent: 15%">
        {% for ad in ads %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('ads', image_key = ad.image_key, posts = ad.image_key)}}">{{ad.title}}
        {% endfor %}
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <h2>Previous Ads</h2>
        <dl class="desc-info" style ="text-indent: 15%">
            {% for inactive_ad in inactive_ads %}
            <dt><a href="{{ url_for('ads', image_key = inactive_ad.image_key, posts = inactive_ad.image_key)}}">{{inactive_ad.title}}</dt>
            {% endfor %}
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of the other links are working correctly. `desc-info` just aligns the text to the left. I have nearly the identical code on another page but the only difference here is that the `for` loop is in the second column instead of a few rows of `href` links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotton to close your anchor tags with `</a>`.

So under 'Live Ads' (think you also forgot the `<dt></dt>` tags here):

```
<dt>
  <a href="{{ url_for('ads', image_key = ad.image_key, posts = ad.image_key)}}">{{ad.title}}</a>
</dt>
```

And under 'Previous Ads':

```
<dt>
  <a href="{{ url_for('ads', image_key = inactive_ad.image_key, posts = inactive_ad.image_key)}}">{{inactive_ad.title}}</a>
</dt>
```